# recovering raid5 (mdraid) after clean OS install (Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

========

**After having to reinstall the OS I am having trouble accessing data stored on a RAID5 group built on 8 HDDs using mdraid. Advice much appreciated!**

I have a DIY home NAS server built on Intel Atom (Zotac NM10-DTX WiFi), 8 x 2TB WD Caviar HDDs connected via a HighPoint-RocketRAID 2680, as well as a 64GB SSD for the OS.

The setup was running fine for nearly 2 years (on Ubuntu Server 10.4 LTS) and using mdraid (it turned out I could get better performance using the RAID adapter only for connecting the drives and using mdraid to build a 14TB RAID5 array).

I recently started to experience some performance issues (reads and writes became slow - both when accessing the data from other hosts in my network and also running dd locally on the NAS server) so I decided to update the OS at it's been a while (I only had automatic security updates). The update went horribly wrong with the OS not even booting after the update - so I decided to make a clean install of Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Thanks to askubuntu I managed to build the driver for the RocketRAID 2680 and I can see all 8 drives (/dev/sdb through /dev/sdi) and running mdadm --examine returns:

```
/dev/sdb1:
Magic : a92b4efc
Version : 0.90.00
UUID : e667bd7d:d55be409:e9e4094c:aa5ad989 (local to host wega)
Creation Time : Wed Jan  5 16:47:34 2011
Raid Level : raid5
Used Dev Size : 1953431232 (1862.94 GiB 2000.31 GB)
Array Size : 13674018624 (13040.56 GiB 14002.20 GB)
Raid Devices : 8
Total Devices : 8
Preferred Minor : 0

Update Time : Tue Oct 15 18:36:41 2013
State : clean
Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0
Checksum : d1fdf40 - correct
Events : 1010

Layout : left-symmetric
Chunk Size : 64K

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
3     3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
4     4       8       81        4      active sync   /dev/sdf1
5     5       8       97        5      active sync   /dev/sdg1
6     6       8      113        6      active sync   /dev/sdh1
7     7       8      129        7      active sync   /dev/sdi1
```

I was also able to activate /ded/md0 by running:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1
```

...returning:

```
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 8 drives.
```

## + NOW FOR THE PROBLEM: +

While the array appears to have restarted successfully, I don't see my 14TB partition which I have created 2 years ago (and used ever since to store all of my data). Running cfdisk shows only a single Linux partition with ~1.8TB of capacity and ~12TB of unused space:

```
Disk Drive: /dev/md0
Size: 14002195070976 bytes, 14002.1 GB
Heads: 2   Sectors per Track: 4   Cylinders: 3418504656

Name     Flags  Part Type   FS Type     [Label]     Size (MB)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Pri/Log     Free Space              0.06                  
md0p1           Primary     Linux                   1750274.33
                Pri/Log     Free Space              12251920.69
```

The same also appears when running mdadm --detail /dev/md0

```
/dev/md0:
Version : 0.90    
Creation Time : Wed Jan  5 16:47:34 2011
Raid Level : raid5
Array Size : 13674018624 (13040.56 GiB 14002.20 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1953431232 (1862.94 GiB 2000.31 GB)
Raid Devices : 8
Total Devices : 8
Preferred Minor : 0
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Wed Oct 16 11:07:25 2013
State : clean 
Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Layout : left-symmetric
Chunk Size : 64K

UUID : e667bd7d:d55be409:e9e4094c:aa5ad989 (local to host wega)
Events : 0.1010

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
4       8       81        4      active sync   /dev/sdf1
5       8       97        5      active sync   /dev/sdg1
6       8      113        6      active sync   /dev/sdh1
7       8      129        7      active sync   /dev/sdi1
```

If I understand correctly - the difference between "Array Size" and "Used Device Size" (2TB vs 14TB) means that there is a problem. I do not want to try to mount the partition until I understand what is going on (to avoid any changes to the data which would inhibit be from getting again access to my RAID group).

**Any advice would be very much appreciated as I have been using this NAS server for all backups and digital media.**

## Did I forget to flip one last switch or am I totally screwed?

Answer (score 0):

Used Device Size means each individual disk is 2 TB.  Don't use `cfdisk` as it is an old buggy POS that only understands the msdos partition table, which doesn't support disks > 2TB.  Use `parted` instead, which supports gpt.

More importantly, I don't think you even have a partition table in the raid array.  It is more typical to just format the whole array rather than partition it up, so just try mounting the array.